# Changing locale within the app effectively

Tags: android, dialog, widget, locale

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2900144/5754623) answer, I'm using the following code in the `onCreate()` method of each activity:

```
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.setLocale(newLocale);
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

But this does not effectively update the configuration. The following problems need to be resolved:

1. The layout direction of the `dialogs` seems to be overridden by the system, which should have been handled by `conf.setLocale(newLocale)`.
2. The same is with some widgets such as `TimePicker`.
3. Numbers in `NumberPicker` and `TimePicker` are overridden as well.

What should be the effective approach here?

Comment: At what point exactly in onCreate are you using that block of code?

Comment: Before setContentview() and after super.onCreate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a bit too early to post an answer to my question, but adding `Locale.setDefault(newLocale)` to the code above solves all the three problems mentioned.